# I need help to display all even numbers from an input set of 20 integers in java 13

Tags: java

I need help in displaying all the even numbers from an input set of 20 random integers, I only know to display 1 integer. (Beginner)

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter an integer >> ");
  int num = input.nextInt();     

 if(isEven(num))
     System.out.println("The integer entered is even.");
  else
     System.out.println("The integer entered is odd.");   


 public static boolean isEven(int number)
   {

      return (number % 2) == 0;
   }
```

Comment: I need to ask the user to input 20 or more random integers and the code will tell if the input numbers are even numbers

Comment: Use a [loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take  input using a loop.

```java
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          for(int i=1;i<=20;i++) {
              System.out.print("Enter an integer >> ");
              int num = input.nextInt();     
              if( num%2 == 0)
                  System.out.println("The integer entered is even.");
              else
                 System.out.println("The integer entered is odd.");   
          }
```